# How to render sprite array efficiently in j2me game?

Tags: java, arrays

I am working on a landscape java game.

I have a sprite array like this;

```
Sprite stickArray[] = new Sprite[10];
```

and initializing it like this with visibility as false.

```
for (int j = 0; j < stickArray.length; j++) {

        if (stickArray[j] != null) {

            stickArray[j].setPosition(stickX, stickY);
            stickArray[j].setVisible(false);
        }
    }
```

Later I want to position it like one after another vertically on repeating a key.pressBool is false initially.

```
public void keyRepeatInGame(int keyCode) {
    int gameKey = getGameAction(keyCode);
    Graphics g = getGraphics();
    if (gameKey == FIRE || keyCode == KEY_NUM5) {
        pressBool = true;
    }
}
```

Later I have written code like this;
Initially one Sticksprite is there.above this sprite, I want to place each sticks on clalling keyrepeat()in space key.

```
for (int i = 0; i < stickArray.length; i++) {
            if (pressBool) {
                if (i == 0) {
                    stickArray[i].setPosition(stickSprite.getX(),
                            stickSprite.getY() - stickSprite.getHeight());
                    stickArray[i].setVisible(true);
                } else {
                    stickArray[i].setPosition(stickArray[i-1].getX(),
                            stickArray[i-1].getY() - stickArray[i].getHeight());
                    stickArray[i].setVisible(true);
                }
            }
        }
```

This code is working partially.Stick is getting added on the sprite,all at once.

How can I change the code to make the sticks repeatedly getting added on calling keyrepeat() only, and make it visible one by one properly?

Comment: Question is not clear, post an http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I changed the code with an additional condition and break statement like this;

```
if (pressBool) {
                if (stickSprite != null && !stickArray[i].isVisible()
                        && stickArray[i] != null) {
                    if (i == 0) {
                        stickArray[i].setPosition(
                                stickSprite.getX(),
                                stickSprite.getY());
                        stickArray[i].setVisible(true);
                        break;
                    } else if (i > 0) {
                        stickArray[i].setPosition(
                                stickArray[i].getX(),
                                stickArray[i - 1].getY()
                                        - stickArray[i].getHeight());
                        stickArray[i].setVisible(true);
                        break;
                    }
                }
            }
```

It worked.